# How to get regex matched group values

Tags: java, regex

I have following lines of code

```
String time = "14:35:59.99";
String timeRegex = "(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(.([0-9]{1,3}))?";
String hours, minutes, seconds, milliSeconds;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(timeRegex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(time);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    hours = matcher.replaceAll("$1");
    minutes = matcher.replaceAll("$4");
    seconds = matcher.replaceAll("$5");
    milliSeconds = matcher.replaceAll("$7");
}
```

I am getting hours, minutes, seconds, and milliSeconds using the `matcher.replace` method and back references of regex groups.  Is there any better method to get value of regex groups. I tried

```
hours = matcher.group(1);
```

but it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:477)
    at com.abnamro.cil.test.TimeRegex.main(TimeRegex.java:70)
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are still checking `matcher.matches() == True` first, right?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

It works fine if you avoid calling `matcher.replaceAll`. When you call `replaceAll` it forgets any previous matches.

```
String time = "14:35:59.99";
String timeRegex = "([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?:\\.([0-9]{1,3}))?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(timeRegex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(time);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String hours = matcher.group(1);
    String minutes = matcher.group(2);
    String seconds = matcher.group(3);
    String miliSeconds = matcher.group(4);
    System.out.println(hours + ", " + minutes  + ", " + seconds + ", " + miliSeconds);
}
```

Notice that I've also made a couple of improvements to your regular expression:

- I've used non-capturing groups `(?: ... )` for the groups that you aren't interested in capturing.
- I've changed `.` which matches any character to `\\.` which matches only a dot.

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/YeL7Z#view_edit_box)

Comment: I needed to use matcher.find() as the check rather than matcher.matches() when I implemented this. Other than that, this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 26):

It works if you use `matcher.find()` before calling the group function.

Comment: i have a situation where `find` returns true but groups throws an exception

Comment: @dopatraman have you checked ´index in Matcher.group()´ <= Matcher.groupCount() ?